# What is equivalent to `Rails.config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations` in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I like to turn this on in my rails app configuration:

```
Rails.config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

Nonetheless, I realized this has been deprecated. What would be equivalent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Rails 6.1 release notes](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v6.1.0):

> - Deprecate `config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations` in favor of
>   `config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translations`.
>
>   New generalized configuration option now determines whether an error should be raised for missing translations in controllers and views.

You should be able to say this instead:

```
config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

[Rails 7 removes the deprecated configuration option](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/7_0_release_notes.html#action-view):

> **6.1 Removals**
>
> - Remove deprecated `Rails.config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations`

Comment: My  test and development environment configs have the correct statement in place. Could a gem be using the deprecated logic? If so how the heck do I find it? Thanks!

Comment: @MattJamison Maybe ask a new question including any stack traces or other details you have.

Comment: One thing that we bumped into was when calling `I18n.t` outside of views (e.g. in a sidekiq job). Then this config seems to have no effect. As far as I could work out, it only applies to uses inside views. Rails wraps `I18n.translate` with its own `translate` (aliased to `t`), and applies the config only then. TL;DR if you're calling `I18n.t` directly, you cannot rely on this config :)

Comment: As of rails 7.0.5, `config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translation = true` raises for [*any* missing translation](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/47057).